# Juju bootstrap wrong Maas API

Tags: juju, maas

Ubuntu 16.04
Maas 2.0.0 (beta3+bzr4941)
Juju 2.0beta7

While attempting to bootstrap to an arbitrary MaaS node, Juju tries to access Maas api version 1.0 which does not exist.

```
2016-05-30 19:16:49 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:448 Get http://<IPv4 address>/MAAS/api/1.0/version/: dial tcp <IPv4 address>:80: getsockopt: connection timed out
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: subprocess encountered error code 1
```

How to I specify Juju to use Maas api 2.0?  I've tried both with and without `export JUJU_DEV_FEATURE_FLAGS=maas2` with no difference in results.

Comment: Juju 2.0 should detect the MAAS API version. It's not behind a feature flag in beta7. Can you provide more details on how you set it up and double check the MAAS version you're running? What config did you use to setup communication? (minus any secrets)